# Как вернуть массив обьектов, в котором содержится определенное свойство ключа

Tags: javascript

```
function findUsersByName(users, name) {}
function findUsersByString(users, str) {}
const users = [
  {
    id: 101,
    name: 'Denis',
    city: 'Kyiv',
  },
  {
    id: 102,
    name: 'Alexandr',
    city: 'Lviv',
  }
]
console.log(findUsersByName(users, 'Denis')) // ===> [ { id: 101, name: 'Denis', city: 'Kyiv' }, { id: 106, name: 'Denis', city: 'Lviv' } ]
console.log(findUsersByString(users, 'Den')) // ===> [ { id: 101, name: 'Denis', city: 'Kyiv' }, { id: 106, name: 'Denis', city: 'Lviv' } ]
```

функция findUsersByName() должна возвращать массив обьектов если в нем есть свойство 'Denis'
функция findUsersByString() должна возвращать массив обьектов если в нем есть часть свойство 'Den'

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается? Что именно нужно подсказать?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если нет свойств, у которых значение - это объект, то можно так однострочниками

```js
const users = [{
    id: 101,
    name: 'Denis',
    city: 'Kyiv',
  },
  {
    id: 102,
    name: 'Alexandr',
    city: 'Lviv',
  },
  {
    id: 106,
    name: 'Denis',
    city: 'Lviv'
  }
];

const findUsersByName = (users, name) => users.filter(user => Object.values(user).some(value => value === name));
const findUsersByString = (users, str) => users.filter(user => Object.values(user).some(value => ('' + value).indexOf(str) !== -1));

console.log(findUsersByName(users, 'Denis')) // ===> [ { id: 101, name: 'Denis', city: 'Kyiv' }, { id: 106, name: 'Denis', city: 'Lviv' } ]
console.log(findUsersByString(users, 'Den')) // ===> [ { id: 101, name: 'Denis', city: 'Kyiv' }, { id: 106, name: 'Denis', city: 'Lviv' } ]
```

Если же есть свойства, у которых значение - это объект, то просто рекурсивно запускаете [алгоритм Алексея Шиманского](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1435008/385375)

Answer (score 1):

- Объявляем пустой массив (result)
- Для обхода массива используется цикл: for..in,  for..of, forEach, do-while, while-do
- Для обхода свойств объекта можно использовать **[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)**
- Во втором цикле (Object.values)  просто надо использовать `if`. Если значение совпадает с указанным, то объект (элемент) из внешнего цикла заносится через метод `push` в массив `result`, который до всех циклов был объявлен.